# Populating a data frame in R in a loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to populate a data frame from within a for loop in R. The names of the columns are generated dynamically within the loop and the value of some of the loop variables is used as the values while populating the data frame. For instance the name of the current column could be some variable name as a string in the loop, and the column can take the value of the current iterator as its value in the data frame.

I tried to create an empty data frame outside the loop, like this

```
d = data.frame()
```

But I cant really do anything with it, the moment I try to populate it, I run into an error

```
 d[1] = c(1,2)
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, value = c(1, 2)) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 0
```

What may be a good way to achieve what I am looking to do. Please let me know if I wasnt clear.

Comment: Populate a `list` instead of a `data.frame` and turn it into a `data.frame` after the loop.

Comment: Thanks Roland, I am a n00b, can you please elaborate more?  How to declare the list, and how to convert it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
 iterations = 10
 variables = 2

 output <- matrix(ncol=variables, nrow=iterations)

 for(i in 1:iterations){
  output[i,] <- runif(2)

 }

 output
```

and then turn it into a `data.frame`

```
 output <- data.frame(output)
 class(output)
```

what this does:

1. create a matrix with rows and columns according to the expected growth
2. insert 2 random numbers into the matrix
3. convert this into a dataframe *after* the loop has finished.

Answer (score 60):

It is often preferable to avoid loops and use vectorized functions. If that is not possible there are two approaches:

1. Preallocate your `data.frame`. This is not recommended because indexing is slow for `data.frames`.
2. Use another data structure in the loop and transform into a `data.frame` afterwards. A `list` is very useful here.

Example to illustrate the general approach:

```
mylist <- list() #create an empty list

for (i in 1:5) {
  vec <- numeric(5) #preallocate a numeric vector
  for (j in 1:5) { #fill the vector
    vec[j] <- i^j 
  }
  mylist[[i]] <- vec #put all vectors in the list
}
df <- do.call("rbind",mylist) #combine all vectors into a matrix
```

In this example it is not necessary to use a `list`, you could preallocate a `matrix`. However, if you do not know how many iterations your loop will need, you should use a `list`.

Finally here is a vectorized alternative to the example loop:

```
outer(1:5,1:5,function(i,j) i^j)
```

As you see it's simpler and also more efficient.

Comment: You can simplify your vectorised version even more like: `outer(1:5,1:5,"^")`

Comment: Hi Roland, if we don't know anything about the number of iteration and the number of columns (using the example above that you have given), how do we do for loop or function, please I want your explanation since I like your example. I would appreciate if you can give like the above example so that I can customize it for big data.

Comment: @Stackuser This approach is suitable for medium sized data. For big data you should use something more efficient. Not knowing the number of columns is probably the result of a design flaw.

Comment: Thanks@Ronald! Can you recommend me reference because I have 37-time series data, each with 30 years of data (1110 in total) and I don't know the number of iteration and I am building a model and getting prediction errors and extracting all coefficients, p-values, prediction erros (observed - predicted value), etc? I also want to know how can we subset at any section of data e.g, if I want to make a loop (function) in every 21th or 19th value of this time series data and making prediciton and store the results somewhere? thanks!

Comment: That's not big data. And sorry, but don't do free consulting.

Comment: I am happy to get your consultation and willing to pay for your consultancy service because I read most of your comments and they are very critical and to the point!

Answer (score 22):

this works too.

```
df = NULL
for (k in 1:10)
    {
       x = 1
       y = 2
       z = 3
       df = rbind(df, data.frame(x,y,z))
     }
```

output will look like this

```
df #enter

x y z #col names
1 2 3
```

Comment: This works great for small cases and is the simplest in my opinion, but be aware that it becomes prohibitively slow and resource intensive for large or even medium datasets because it is actually rebuilding the entire data.frame every time you add a row.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Notable1, works for me with the tidytextr
Create a dataframe with the name of files in one column and content in other.

```
    diretorio <- "D:/base"
    arquivos <- list.files(diretorio, pattern = "*.PDF")
    quantidade <- length(arquivos)

#
df = NULL
for (k in 1:quantidade) {

      nome = arquivos[k]
      print(nome)
      Sys.sleep(1) 
      dados = read_pdf(arquivos[k],ocr = T)
      print(dados)
      Sys.sleep(1)
      df = rbind(df, data.frame(nome,dados))
      Sys.sleep(1)
}
Encoding(df$text) <- "UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a case in where I was needing to use a data frame within a for loop function. *In this case, it was the "efficient", however, keep in mind that the database was small and the iterations in the loop were very simple*. But maybe the code could be useful for some one with similar conditions.

The *for loop* purpose was to use the *raster extract* function along five locations (i.e. 5 Tokio, New York, Sau Paulo, Seul & Mexico city) and each location had their respective raster grids. I had a spatial point database with more than 1000 observations allocated within the 5 different locations and I was needing to extract information from 10 different raster grids (two grids per location). Also, for the subsequent analysis, I was not only needing the raster values but also the unique ID for each observations.

After preparing the spatial data, which included the following tasks:

1. Import points shapefile with the *readOGR* function (rgdap package)
2. Import raster files with the *raster* function (raster package)
3. Stack grids from the same location into one file, with the function *stack* (raster package)

Here the *for loop* code with the use of a *data frame*:

*1. Add stacked rasters per location into a list*

```
raslist <- list(LOC1,LOC2,LOC3,LOC4,LOC5)
```

*2. Create an empty dataframe, this will be the output file*

```
TB <- data.frame(VAR1=double(),VAR2=double(),ID=character())
```

*3. Set up for loop function*

```
L1 <- seq(1,5,1) # the location ID is a numeric variable with values from 1 to 5 

for (i in 1:length(L1)) {
  dat=subset(points,LOCATION==i) # select corresponding points for location [i] 
  t=data.frame(extract(raslist[[i]],dat),dat$ID) # run extract function with points & raster stack for location [i]
  names(t)=c("VAR1","VAR2","ID") 
  TB=rbind(TB,t)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

was looking for the same and the following may be useful as well.

```
a <- vector("list", 1)
for(i in 1:3){a[[i]] <- data.frame(x= rnorm(2), y= runif(2))}
a
rbind(a[[1]], a[[2]], a[[3]])
```